# If I registered to vote in the nov 2016 elections, will I also be registered to vote in proceeding special elections?

Tags: united-states, voter-registration

A Kansas Representative was recently pulled into the Trump team and handed his resignation in. We'll have a special election on April 11th for a replacement. Does my voter registration still count, or do I need to register again for this election?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you were eligible to vote for the general election and you voted you will definitely not need to re-register for the special election. Some states may expire your registration if you do not vote for multiple election cycles.

I'm guessing you were referring to Senator Sessions from Alabama; I was not able to find any information on voter registration expiration there so I would guess it doesn't happen. You can contact them yourself to confirm though, their website is [here](https://myinfo.alabamavotes.gov/)

Comment: I dont think registration will ever expire.  You may however be marked inactive and either have to show ID at the polls or fill out an affidavit ballot depending on state and local laws.